# How to enclose appended value in single quotes from function into a sql string in python

Tags: python

Here i am trying to enclose an appended value coming from function into a sql string in python
but somehow i am not able to it.

getname is returning Puru

```
    def getValue(getname):
    sql= '''SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = '''+getname
```

I want to return it in this form in single quotes

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'Puru'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three ways to achieve what you want:

string concatenation

```
sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = '"+getname+"'"
```

string.format()

```
sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = '{}'".format(getname)
```

format string (requires python 3.6+)

```
sql = f"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = '{getname}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your understanding other than `str.format()` python also provides  `Template` class from `string` module.
`Templates` provide simpler string substitutions in `python`. Instead of the normal `%`-based substitutions, Templates support `$`-based substitutions.

**for ex:**

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> sql = Template("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES "
                   "WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = '$getname'")
>>> sql.substitute(getname='Puru')
"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = 'Puru'"
```

The `$getname` names a substitution placeholder matching a mapping key of **"getname"**. But I would recommend you to use `str.format()` method which is more readable and widely used for string formatting in `python`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace the `'''` with `"`. Otherwise Python will not know how to interpret the `'` in the middle. If you don't want the line to get too long, you can wrap in in parentheses:

```py
sql = ("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES "
       "WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = ") + getname
```

Edit: I have to point out the dangers of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and creating these queries on the fly. There are numerous libraries that will do it for you in a safe manner. But I have a feeling/hope this won't end up in production code anyway.

Comment: i want to insert getname in single quotes

Comment: Ah, I have missed that. Try: `sql = ("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES "
       "WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG = '{}'").format(getname)`